# Java file placement

Tags: java

When I learned Java, I put my all my files in the bin folder of my JDK folder. Then I compile my code in the command prompt I have to change the directory so that it goes to the bin folder. It looks like this:`C:\Users\MdDaddyJr\Desktop\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>`. Have I been putting the files in the wrong place the whole time? I am not using any IDEs.

Comment: You can create a `workspace` directory somewhere in your user home directory and create new subdirecties for each project. Put your source files in there. Using the `bin` folder of the jdk is completely wrong. May work, but wrong.

Comment: are you using an IDE? Are you talking about your class files? Personally I have never put any files where you are.... I use netbeans maven projects typically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have not set up your environment correctly. 
Few points to start with:

1. Add this `C:\Users\MdDaddyJr\Desktop\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` to your PATH environment variable - this will allow you to execute the `javac` and `java` commands from any folder, which means you don't need to change to the ../bin nor would you need to type the full path each time. So you can simply do:

   c:\Dev\workspace\project1>javac MyClass.java
2. Create a dedicated folder where you place your Java sources and organise them in packages (i.e. subfolders) - see this exhaustive answer: [What strategy do you use for package naming in Java projects and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533102/what-strategy-do-you-use-for-package-naming-in-java-projects-and-why)
3. When compiling your files you need to be in the root folder where the package hierarchy starts. So for example, if your workspace is in `C:\Dev\workspace\project1` and your class `MyClass.java` is in package `my.study` that is, it is in `C:\Dev\workspace\project1\my\study\MyClass.java`, then to compile it you do:

   c:\Dev\workspace\project1>javac my\study\MyClass.java

This will create the class file at `C:\Dev\workspace\project1\my\study\MyClass.class`, which you can then execute like so (assuming it has a main() method):

```
c:\Dev\workspace\project1>java my.study.MyClass
```

Of course such exercises are OK when dealing with isolated source files and to get a feel of the language. The moment you start writing some real-life programs with multiple inter-dependent classes and 3rd party JAR dependencies, the manual compilation above becomes extremely difficult to manage.  For this, look at one of the popular Java IDEs: Eclipse, IntelliJ (community edition is free) or NetBeans.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You an put your files in any folder as you wish but its not good to keep it in the `bin`. But you have to set the `path` correctly to `C:\Users\MdDaddyJr\Desktop\jdk1.7.0_51\bin`. Then only you will be able to execute your program.

You can set the path by using this link https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml