# Data access Objects and JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

Apologies for the "pedantic" question, however I have been wondering how to structure the following.  If I am building a JPA type application, my persistent classes (annotated with @Table etc) may be collected in a foo.bar.entities package.    However, I may also have objects that are of a similar structure (POJO) that are not use for persistence.  Where would I place these so that it was clear that there function was other than JPA; foo.bar.dto (for data transfer object) - or am I confusing my terminology?  Maybe they are "model" classes - although that is really what the entities are?

Comment: This is highly opinionated and the answers probably also will. For instance see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/258196/java-application-structure-horizontal-vs-vertical-split/258197#258197 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533102/what-strategy-do-you-use-for-package-naming-in-java-projects-and-why.

Comment: Thanks - I will have a read of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term 'dto' is mostly used to refer to these kind of objects. Use vertical slice architecture to place these classes under a different package.

[image]

Now, you can place dto's under dto package and entity/domain classes under domain package. You can also use entities as your package name, but just be consistent all across your project with your naming conventions.